# Add text after semicolon in R

Tags: r, tidyr, grepl

I have a dataframe which has a colon of such values

```
test1=data.frame(c("ABC 01; 02; 03", "test2 01; 02; 03"))
```

I would like to insert text before the semicolon, like this:

```
test1=data.frame(c("ABC 01; ABC 02; ABC 03", "test2 01; test2 02; test2 03"))
```

can someone show me how to do this?
thank you!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a two-step `tidyverse` solution:

```
library(tidyverse)    
test1 %>%
  mutate(
    # create temporary variable containing text string:
    temp = str_replace(var, "(\\w+).*", " \\1"),
    # add text string each time there is ";" to the left:
    var= str_replace_all(var, "(?<=;)", temp)) %>%
  # remove `temp`:
  select(-temp)
                           var
1       ABC 01; ABC 02; ABC 03
2 test2 01; test2 02; test2 03
```

How this works:

- 1. using `str_replace` we define the string-initial alphanumeric substring (`\\w+`) as a capture group (by placing it into parentheses) and refer to it, and it alone, in the replacement clause using backreference (`\\1`), where we also add one whitespace (before the backreference)
- 2. next, using `str_replace_all` we add the text string in `temp` to the strings in `var`on the condition that there be a literal `;` immediately to the left (this type of *conditional* matching is called positive look-behind; its syntax is `(?<= ...)`)

Data:

```
test1=data.frame(var = c("ABC 01; 02; 03", "test2 01; 02; 03"))
```

Answer (score 4):

Using only base R:

```
test1$y <- mapply(
  \(org, key) gsub("; ([0-9]+)", key, org),
  org = test1$x, key = sprintf("; %s \\1", sub(" .+", "", test1$x))
)

                 x                            y
1   ABC 01; 02; 03       ABC 01; ABC 02; ABC 03
2 test2 01; 02; 03 test2 01; test2 02; test2 03
```

Data

```
test1 <- data.frame(x = c("ABC 01; 02; 03", "test2 01; 02; 03"))
```

Answer (score 1):

Another regex option could be to parse it all in capture groups:

```r
fun <- \(x) gsub("(\\w+) (\\d+); (\\d+); (\\d+)", "\\1 \\2; \\1 \\3; \\1 \\4", x)
```

Then with either `dplyr` or `base`:

```
library(dplyr)

test1 |>
  mutate(result = fun(string))
```

```
test1$result <- sapply(test1$string, fun)
```

Output:

```r
            string                       result
1   ABC 01; 02; 03       ABC 01; ABC 02; ABC 03
2 test2 01; 02; 03 test2 01; test2 02; test2 03
```

Data:

```r
test1 <- data.frame(string = c("ABC 01; 02; 03", "test2 01; 02; 03"))
```

Answer (score 1):

Using *strsplit* and *paste*. Split on space then paste 1st item to all items excluding 1st item:

```
test1$new <- sapply(strsplit(test1$x, " ", fixed = TRUE),
                    function(i) paste(paste(i[ 1 ], i[ -1 ]), collapse = " "))
test1
#                  x                          new
# 1   ABC 01; 02; 03       ABC 01; ABC 02; ABC 03
# 2 test2 01; 02; 03 test2 01; test2 02; test2 03
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an option using `stringr` functions.

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

test1 = data.frame(col = c("ABC 01; 02; 03", "test2 01; 02; 03"))

result <- test1 %>%
  mutate(common = str_extract(col, '\\w+'), 
         parts = str_split(str_remove(col, common), ';\\s+'),
         new_string = purrr::map2_chr(common, parts, 
                         str_c, sep = " ", collapse = ";"))

result

#               col common       parts                  new_string
#1   ABC 01; 02; 03    ABC  01, 02, 03       ABC  01;ABC 02;ABC 03
#2 test2 01; 02; 03  test2  01, 02, 03 test2  01;test2 02;test2 03

result$new_string

#[1] "ABC  01;ABC 02;ABC 03"       "test2  01;test2 02;test2 03"
```

You may drop the columns that you don't need from `result`.